# Permissions issue with Ubuntu shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

I have a shell script in my /home/myuser/.local/bin/ folder. When I run the script I get:

```
$ ~/.local/bin/renew_ssl.sh
bash: /home/myuser/.local/bin/renew_ssl.sh: Permission denied
```

If I run it with sudo I get:

```
$ sudo ~/.local/bin/renew_ssl.sh
sudo: /home/myuser/.local/bin/renew_ssl.sh: command not found
```

So I tried to grant execute permissions:

```
$ sudo chmod -x ~/.local/bin/renew_ssl.sh
```

But this doesn't seem to stick:

```
ls -l  ~/.local/bin/renew_ssl.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myuser 149 Apr 13 14:24 /home/myuser/.local/bin/renew_ssl.sh
```

This is the content of the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl stop nginx
sudo certbot renew
sudo docker stop home-assistant
sudo docker start home-assistant
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

...and this is my path:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/myuser/bin:/home/myuser/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.
Can anyone tell me why I can't execute this script? (or even assign execute permissions to it?)

Comment: Seems `myuser`already owns the script so `chmod 755 ~/.local/bin/renew_ssl.sh` should work

Comment: `chmod -x` *removes* execute permission. Use `chmod +x` to add.

Comment: It should be easy to remember: `+` is addition, `-` is subtraction.